# First hitting time for generalized Pólya urn

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms

I have looked around the literature but I've not found a clean answer to the following. Imagine that you have a generalized Pólya urn (GPU) in the sense of Pemantle's survey (Section 2.1 in [Pemantle07](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/reinforce.pdf)). What is the expected time until the ratio of white balls to black balls is equal to $p$ (assuming that the initial ratio is $p_0$)? An answer for the much simpler case of the GPU with a diagonal $A$ matrix would also be interesting. A non-trivial upper bound would also suffice.

Comment: There is more than one way to generalise a Pólya urn, so you may need to give more detail.  In many cases I would think the answer to your question will be an infinite expectation or worse.